# How to prevent regular expression test toggling when using a variable?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I just noticed the following *strange* behavior (both in browsers and [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs):

```
> a = /^\/foo/g
/^\/foo/g
> a.test("/foo")
true
> a.test("/foo")
false
> a.test("/foo")
true
> a.test("/foo")
false
> a.test("/foo")
true
```

What kind of mad science we have here? How can I prevent this behavior?

I just want to have a regex variable that checks if a string matches the pattern globally.

---

[Documentation pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) don't seem to bring some light there... I'd really appreciate a link to documentation references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [lastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) of your regex to 0 after each test.

```
a = /^\/foo/g
a.test("/foo"); //true
a.test("/foo"); //false
a.test("/foo"); //true
a.lastIndex = 0; //reset the index to start the next match at beginning
a.test("/foo"); //true
```

Comment: Or just remove the `g` flag.